# Tomcat cannot access application management but can access host manager

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, tomcat8

I have a strange question, I use Tomcat 8.0.33. I edit the tomcat-user.xml like that :

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
          version="1.0">
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-script"/>
    <user username="xxx" password="xxx" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

I can login in host manager page using "admin" account, but when I go to "manage app" page and type the same username and password, it shows (in firefox 44):

```
The connection was reset

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

I deploy the tomcat server in amazon cloud server, I also deploy the same server in my own server, where everything could correctly work.

Comment: Please edit your post to remove the credentials and/or site - this will quickly become an issue.

Comment: Sorry, don't know the rules.